# Use Find and select all the results

Tags: vba, excel

How do I can select all the results of the Find function and then copy and paste in a new column of the same Sheet with a macro

Below is an example

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there is no native VBA functions which will let you select all instances of a search string in a range. Luckily for you, there have been other people before you who has wanted this functionality so some user-created code for it has been made. An example is the `FindAll`-function presented by Chip Pearson [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx), which I believe you should be able to adapt to your needs quite easily. It returns a `range`-object containing all the cells containing the search-text, so pasting that range to a column should be fairly trivial.